# How to do the initial design for a DVD database?

Tags: database, database-design

I'm trying to create a database that'll let me keep track of my DVDs and Blu-rays (more library, less imdb).

Where I'm running into trouble is trying to keep track of things like television and movie series. For example:

```
Episode Title: "The New Guy"
Disc Position: 1
Case Name: Warehouse 13 Season 3
Series Name: Warehouse 13
Series Number: 3
```

I think that should be a separate table (tables?), but I'm not quite sure what it should look like or how to link it to the rest of it.

Here's what I've got so far for the other tables:

**Title Table** *(movies or tv series episodes)*:
* PK - titleID
* titleName
* description

**Disc Table**
* PK - discID
* FK - titleID
* discPosition *(as in the 1st disc in a case)*
* format
* discNotes
* discStatus *(as in checked in/out/missing)*

**Case Table**
* PK - caseID
* FK - discID
* caseName
* caseStatus

---- Maybe something like this???----

**Series Table**
* PK - seriesID
* seriesName

**Season Table**
* PK - seasonID
* FK - seriesID
* seasonNumber

Then how do I link it together?

Answer (score 0):

The data model depends on what you want to be able to do with the data. What do you want to be able to query/display/insert/update?

What you have sounds possible. I might consider something like this:

```
Shelf_item
----------
PK id
name
desc
series
episodes

has many 

Contents
--------
CD1
CD2

and types table 

Item_types
----------
dvd
bluray
cd
```

If you do have separate tables for series/episodes etc you might want to consider also noting what series/episodes are available in a corresponding table so you can do queries to indicate which episodes are missing.

I'd probably want to add tables to state where in the house each item was located and if it was out on loan and to whom. If this is just for fun consider writing a script to interrogate amazon or similar to get a list of all products that exist so you can compare with what you own etc.

Good luck!

Comment: I don't entirely understand your reply.    
    
What is the purpose of the Contents table? I don't know what you mean by CD1 and CD2.    
    
I want to be able to search by movie, episode, or series title and to be told the location of the disc or discs matching that criteria.     
    
I also want to be able to track whether a case is checked out (as in whether it's upstairs on my shelf) and whether a disc is checked out of a case (so I don't put the case on a shelf while disc 3 is still downstairs).     
    
All this is mainly because I tend to lose things.

Comment: Just a suggestion that you might have a number of CDs/DVDs as part of a title

Comment: Other way around. You might have multiple titles on one CD/DVD.